# What is this enum for in the destructor?

Tags: c++

```
// Destructor.  If there is a C object, delete it.
// We don't need to test ptr_ == NULL because C++ does that for us  

    ~scoped_ptr() {
       enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(C) };
       delete ptr_;
    }
```

Note: C is a template parameter

I know we cant delete a null pointer, an exception will be raised.
So in this case, the enum definition must be doing something to prevent that.
In production, sometimes we dont want to end a program simple because we have a null pointer, we may want to look at alternative scenario, when the pointer is null.
And this code is used in production, almost everywhere?

Thanks guys.

Comment: We can delete a null pointer it is perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: i think my problem was confused with double deletion of pointers. It always raises an exception when double deletion is detected by the compiler. So what is the difference between deleting a null pointer and double deletion?

Comment: @maress: you can "delete" a null pointer as many times as you like (or actually, you can try to delete it, the runtime will detect the null pointer and do nothing)

Comment: @maress: when you apply `delete` on a pointer, it deletes the objects pointed to, and returns the memory to the runtime, but otherwise leaves the pointer itself intact. If you apply `delete` once again, it will access memory that belongs to the runtime, not your applicative code, and does not contain a "living" object any longer... which brings trouble. On the other hand, a null pointer points nowhere, so the implementation of `delete` should check this condition before attempting to access the memory pointed to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it's effectively a static assertion for the deletion. the implementation wants to know if it is dealing with a type whose declaration is visible before deleting the variable, rather than a forward declaration.

Your compiler will emit an error when you ask it the size of an incomplete type:

```
struct S;
enum { Size = sizeof(S) };
```

**Update**

As your compiler and Matthieu M. will tell you -- `delete`-ing an incomplete type is undefined.

Comment: @sharptooth: I would argue that `C` is clearer, and it's faster to type as well :)

Comment: @Justin: it would be worth precising that attempting to `delete` a pointer to an incomplete type is **undefined behavior**, which is why it's worth diagnosing. Boost also has `checked_delete` to the same effect, they could have reused it but it's probably simple enough they did not think it warranted a specific include.

Comment: @sharptooth i can't think of a good reason at this hour -- is there one?

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I can't agree it's cleaner. What if type of `_ptr` is changed later? Then `C` should be changed too, but the compiler wouldn't care.

Comment: @sharptooth: I did not say *cleaNer* but *cleaRer*. `sizeof(C)` has a very clear meaning, `sizeof(*ptr_)`, less so. My colleagues, at least, are not very comfortable with unevaluated operands.

Answer (score 0):

The boost checked_deleter seems better:

```
template<class T> struct checked_deleter
{
    typedef void result_type;
    typedef T * argument_type;
    void operator()(T * p) const;
};
```

Because some compiler may return 0 while T is undefine, in that case

```
enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(T) };
```

is a valid static assert, but checked_deleter will failed.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/checked_delete.html#core.checked_delete.checked_deleter